# Building a Complex Query with Multiple Relationships in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am struggling to write this query.

Essintially, I have several tables.

```
Group
has many users

User
belongs_to_many_groups, has_many_tool_assigned, has_many_ToolStatus_through_ToolAssigned

Tool
belongs_to_many_groups, has_many_tool_assigned

ToolAssigned
belongs_to_user, belongs to tool, has_many_tool_status

ToolStatus
belongs_to_ToolAssigned
```

What I need is a query that will...

1. <strike>Get all the groups an Auth::user() is in</strike>
2. <strike>Get the count of each group's users</strike>
3. Get the count of tool statuses of those users in each group
4. Get the count of toolsAssigned to those users in each group
5. Get the count of toolsAssigned to those users in each groupwhere the type matches 'test' in
   each group.

Need to have all of that data in the $groups variable so I can iterate and show data for the groups for the user that they are in.

```php
 $user = Auth()->user();
 $groups = $user->groups()
            ->withCount('Users')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I'd say the documentation contains everything you can use in terms of getting counts of relationships. For further functionality you may first load your collections and then when iterating them, count specifig items.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models

Comment: @D.Petrov I've looked at this for a while and I'm not seeing what I need. I can get the count of groups->users, but I need to know the total of toolsAssigned of all of the users in the group.